# Partial validation with marshmallow to ingore unknown field

Tags: python, validation, flask, marshmallow

I have searched this as much as I could, read the docs, looked in various posts but i start to believe it is not possible. So I want to have a partial validation schema, for a Flask app, with marshmallow like this

```
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate


class MySchema(Schema):
    product_type = fields.Str(required=True, allow_none=True)
```

and i want to validate a dictionary and ensure that it has the `product_type` field. Now this dictionary might have any number of other fields unknown to me but I don't care, I want to partially validate that the `product_type` exists. For example:

```
data={"product_type":"consumable","other_field1":67,"other_field2":"info"...}
```

this passes no matter what fields are there BUT only if product type is missing it fails.
How is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the marshmallow documentation there is a section ["Handling Unknown Fields"](https://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#handling-unknown-fields), which explains how to handle unknown fields. In addition to the standard procedure, which causes a ValidationError, there is also the option to exclude fields or to include and accept them. The following example shows just one way of using it.

```py
from marshmallow import Schema, fields, validate, INCLUDE

class MySchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        unknown = INCLUDE
    
    product_type = fields.Str(required=True, allow_none=True)
```